# How to visualize struct differences in golang unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, go

It's easy to compare (flat) structs in golang and it's pretty common to have unit tests that verify equality of structs. Now, I'd like to provide developers with proper feedback what exactly went wrong. I know I could implement `VisualizeStructDifference` somehow, but I'd be surprised if it hasn't been done before. I'd be even surprised if it wasn't easily accessible from golangs standard testing tools.

Can you give me some pointers?

An example:

```golang
func TestStruct(t *testing.T) {
    cases := []struct {
        name  string
        input InputStruct
        want  OutputStruct
    }{
        {
            name: "Case A",
            input: InputStruct{
                A: "Input A",
                B: "Input B",
            },
            want: OutputStruct{
                One: "Output One",
                Two: "Output Two",
            },
        },
        // ...
    }
    for _, tc := range cases {
        t.Run(tc.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            result := unitUnderTest(tc.input)
            
            if result != tc.want{
                t.Errorf("Test %v failed: %v", tc.name, VisualizeStructDifference(result, tc.want))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use github.com/google/go-cmp/cmp

Comment: From ^^^ Use cmp.Equal() for deep comparison of structs/maps, and cmp.Diff() to print out verbose diff between objects in comparison

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my use case: `stretchr/testify` provides

```
assert.EqualValuesf(t, tc.want, result, "%v failed", tc.name)
```

Output:

```
Diff:
                                --- Expected
                                +++ Actual
                                @@ -3,3 +3,3 @@
                                  One: (string) (len=10) "Output One",
                                - Two: (string) (len=10) "Output Two",
                                + Two: (string) (len=9) "Output Tw",
```